# Managing of Array for Swift2

Tags: arrays, swift2

What I require to do is store an array of objects that contains string values. I will then use the name of the objects and display on my UITableViewCell. `Person` is another class that manages the string.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

        @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
        var personList = [Person]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            StoreData()            
            super.viewDidLoad()

            myTableView.dataSource = self
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return personList.count
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            cell.textLabel?.text = personList[indexPath.row].name

            return cell
        }
        func StoreData(){
            self.personList.append(Person(name: "Joe Montana", code: "16", description: "Quarterback"))
            self.personList.append(Person(name: "John Snow", code: "18", description: "Forward"))
        }

    }
```

There are 2 questions to my codes.

1. Why when I do a personList.count, it returns a 0?
2. `cell.textLabel?.text = personList[indexPath.row].name` I get an error
   when running this code.

EDIT: 
I tried to put `personList.count` after `self.personList.append(Person(name: "John Snow", code: "18", description: "Forward"))` and it returns a value of 2.

But in

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return personList.count
        }` it still returns 0.

I suspect it has something to do with `self`. Or is it or issues?

Comment: define your personList as `var personList:Array<Person> = []` it should work fine

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work.

Comment: perhaps you need to call `myTableView.reloadData()` after `StoreData()`

Comment: Somewhere (at the end of `viewDidLoad`) you have to call `myTableView.reloadData()`

Comment: @mad_manny I've re-amended my post, the method still returns 0, while at the bottom it returns 2.

Comment: @vadian I've re-amended my post, the method still returns 0, while at the bottom it returns 2.

Comment: did you add the line to reload the table view data?

Comment: @vadian Yes I've did. However it fails to run my part 2 of my question.
 `cell.textLabel?.text = personList[indexPath.row].name` Runtime issue. I suspect it was unable to extract my String value into the cell label.

Comment: Try to spilt the line : `let person = personList[indexPath.row] cell.textLabel?.text = person.name`

Comment: @vadian yes I've split. Now i noticed even more weird things. It doesn't call my `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method.